# Parsing a string into a class hierarchy

Tags: python, parsing, syntax, pseudocode

Suppose there is a string in a format like this:

```
"2 + 3 * (5 + 2) * -1 - 2"
```

(Just an example, it doesn't have to be an arithmetic syntax)

To be parsed to a class-based hierachy

```
add(2,sub(mul(mul(3,add(5,2)),-1),2))
```

I'm looking for an efficient method of doing this parsing. Currently the problem is that I am not sure what this kind of parsing is called. Therefore I can't find the right sources/references. Any suggestions?

Comment: for sources/references start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Overview_of_process

Comment: you might also have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build an efficient parser for a custom language (often referred to as a DSL - domain specific language) then you need to look at parser generators. These typically work as follows:

- You need to put together a grammar for your language in a certain format (the grammar represents the rules of your language).
- The parser generator provides a tool which will read your grammar and generate the lexer & parser code you need to parse statements.
- The generated lexer & parser will be able to read a string, and if the string complies with the grammar you specified, construct an AST (abstract syntax tree) which represents the logical structure of what was parsed.
- You would then typically integrate the lexer & parser into your own tool which actually does something with the generated AST.

Here is a good reference for [parser generators in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing). The only one of these I have experience with is ANTLR, which I can recommend as being very capable and powerful.

It is worth noting that building language grammars and generating parsers can be a fairly laborious process if you have no experience in doing it, and also for very simple examples such as the one provided it would be overkill. However, if you want to build an efficient parser for a non-trivial language then a parser generator is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a legal python expression you can use the [ast module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast-helpers), specifically `ast.parse`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = ast.parse("2 + 3 * (5 + 2) * -1 - 2")
>>> ast.dump(s)
'Module(body=[Expr(value=BinOp(left=BinOp(left=Num(n=2), op=Add(), right=BinOp(l
eft=BinOp(left=Num(n=3), op=Mult(), right=BinOp(left=Num(n=5), op=Add(), right=N
um(n=2))), op=Mult(), right=Num(n=-1))), op=Sub(), right=Num(n=2)))])'
```

Using `ast.Visitor` you can walk through this tree.